# Node js 404 not found error POST method SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: node.js

I am trying to fetch data from database using node.js but 404 not found error is popping up.

I have defined call in  `app.js`

```
app.post('/api/mycall', function (req, res) {
    console.log("try me")
    console.dir(req.body)

    var params = {
        TableName: "orders",

    };

    docClient.scan(params, onScan);

    function onScan(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.error("Unable to scan the table. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
            res.send({ success: false,message:JSON.stringify(err, null, 2)})
        } else {
            res.send( {success: true,orders:data.Items})
        }
    }
});
```

In my frontend part I am fetching data like this

```
const options = {
            method: "post",
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Content-type": "application/json",
                'Authentication': user.getHmac('POST', '/api/mycall')
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        };

        fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_DB_URI + "/mycall", options)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .catch(error => {

                console.error("Error:", error)
                setErrors("There was an error.")
            })
            .then(response => {
                console.log("my res", response);
                if (response.success) {
                    console.log("Success:", response)
                }
                else {
                    console.log("Error:", response)
                    setErrors("There was an error.")

                }
            });


    }
```

So I am getting error 404 not found

> Request URL: http://localhost:3000/api/mycall  Request Method: POST
> Status Code: 404 Not Found Remote  Address: 127.0.0.1:3000 Referrer
> Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

I would appreciate any kind of help

Comment: Does it work when you postman/curl it?

Comment: I am trying directly in app, didn't try with postman

Comment: did you enable `CORS` in your backend?

Comment: yes I did ...const cors = require('cors') and defined corsOptions

Comment: Going back to Dave's question - have you tried `curl`ing it or sending the request through postman?